# Accessing windows application forms from class library in C#

Tags: c#, windows, class

I have a solution in C# with 2 project of 2 different types: windows app and class library. They all share the same namespace but I can't access forms in windows app although I add reference to System.Windows.Form in CL project. Help me, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you require to access the forms within the WinApp, you need to add that WinApp as a reference to the class library.

Answer (score -1):

You can't access windows forms from the libary.